# Pandas процентное отношение в группе, после сортировки

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Коллеги есть таблица в ней заголовки, этаж, класс, бетона и объем для каждого элемента.
[image: сортированная по группам таблица]
Первоначальная сортировка идет по 
tableVolume=table.groupby(['Этаж','Family','Класс Бетона','Type']).sum()

Мой вопрос:  Есть ли какая то возможность в Pandas штатными методами, в первой таблице подсчитать для каждой группы "Этаж","Family","Type", процент доли каждого элемента в группе по "Type".
Коэффициент kf-это доля объема элемента в общей доле рассчитаной для каждой группы этажей, и для типа Family

[image: Что требуется получить красным цветом]

Comment: groupby() по нескольким столбцам и штатные функции агрегирования )

Comment: А если вы замените картинку на таблицу в текстовом виде, то вероятность ответа увеличится.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__не картинкой__) и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Можете выложить ваши данные на какой-нибудь файлообменник?

Comment: А лучше выложить пример данных в прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    a   b   c         vol
0  a1  b1  c1  604.110551
1  a1  b1  c2  533.927707
2  a1  b1  c3  473.258208
3  a1  b2  c4   44.945130
4  a1  b2  c5  292.652712
5  a2  b3  c6   75.820018
6  a2  b3  c6  204.420208
7  a3  b4  c7  975.782327

In [17]: df["kf"] = df.groupby(["a","b"])["vol"].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
    a   b   c         vol        kf
0  a1  b1  c1  604.110551  0.374922
1  a1  b1  c2  533.927707  0.331365
2  a1  b1  c3  473.258208  0.293713
3  a1  b2  c4   44.945130  0.133132
4  a1  b2  c5  292.652712  0.866868
5  a2  b3  c6   75.820018  0.270554
6  a2  b3  c6  204.420208  0.729446
7  a3  b4  c7  975.782327  1.000000
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное, данный совет помог. Все отлично получилось, а я уже думал какую то функцию огромную замутить.